# mail function doesn't work with condition

Tags: php, if-statement, phpmailer

i have a contact form in my site that sends mails using the php's mail function.

This is my code:

```html
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['your-email'])) {


$email_to = "felipepinoredes@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto Codelco";




$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['your-name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['your-email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['your-message'] . "\n\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
?>
```

If i leave it just like that, it won't send the email, but, if i delete the if and leave it like this, it works:

```html
$email_to = "felipepinoredes@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto Codelco";

// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario


$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['your-name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['your-email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['your-message'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
```

But i need the condition, i don't want blank mails sent automatically everytime i load the page.

Help, please.

Comment: Try `if(!empty($_POST['your-email']))`

Comment: Hey! this comment answered fixed my problem. How can i vote you up?

Comment: I posted it as answer if you want to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is sent to our script via POST or GET is always set, if no value was entered it will be set to an empty string. So if we write the following statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['your-email'])) {}
```

Will always evaluate TRUE, even if no value was entered. So to validate our input requiring some value we can use either:

```
if(!empty($_POST['your-email'])) {}
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['your-email']) && !empty($_POST['your-email'])) {} // Redundant
```

In the question's code `if(isset($_POST['your-email'])) {}` always evaluates true, even if `$_POST['your-email']` is empty, causing the `$email_message` to be incomplete.

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks. Thanks also for the feedback about an empty field that counts as "true", didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it could help. But I would try the request if it is in post method first. Maybe you are in get method.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
   if(isset($_POST['your-email'])) {
      ... your code ...
   }
}
```

And I would also validate the input prior to send. Because you are opening backdoors to your code.

```
if(filter_var($_POST['your-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
   ... mail();. ..
}
```